# Regex to match word delimiters in multilingual text

Tags: regex, unicode, multilingual, spell-checking, hunspell

I have a text box that a user can input any text in any language in and I need to split that text into words so that I could pass those words into hunspell spell check. For splitting I use a regexp that matches word delimiters.

At first I used `\W` as a word delimiter to split a text into wrods, but that works only with Latin letters, such as in English language. If I use non-Latin language, it treats every letter of it as `\W`. That's because `\W` is defined as any character that is `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

So far, `(?![-'])[\pP|\pZ|\pC]` seems to tokenize English, Spanish and Russian correctly. It basically says to treat all punctuation characters (except for the hyphen and the apostrophe), all separator characters and all "other" characters (control, private use, etc) as word delimiters. I have excluded hyphen and apostrophe because those usually shouldn't be treated as word delimiters.

I haven't tested it much, just came up with it today, so I thought it would be wise to ask if someone knew of any regex that is more suited for matching word delimiters in a multilingual text.

Note that I'm not concerned with languages that can't be tokenized, such as Japanese, Chinese, Thai, etc.

**Update:** Since people were asking what language I'm using (though it probably shouldn't matter much), I'm using C++ and Qt5's [QRegularExpression](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) class.

Comment: what programming language are you in?

Comment: You can extend the `\W` class using the unicode mode. Or you can use the `\pL` and `\pN` classes

Answer (score 1):

With Java (for example), you can emulate word boundaries like that (don't forget to double escape):

```
(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])[\p{L}\p{N}_]+(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])
```

Where `\p{L}` matches any letters and `\p{N}` any digits.

Thus, you can easily split a string into "words" with: `[^\p{L}\p{N}_]+`

(I don't know the regex flavor you use, but you can probably remove the curly brackets).

Comment: What about hyphen and the apostrophe? They are part of words too. For example, `it's` should be treated as a single word, not as `it` and `s`. Same goes for some languages having `-` in compound words.

Comment: Also, I only need to match just a single word boundary, there is no need for `+`. What I'm doing is something along those lines:
`text.split("(?![-\'])[\\pP|\\pZ|\\pC]");`. For example, for `text = "compound-word, it's a test!"` I get `("compound-word", "it's", "a", "test")`.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP this should work:

```
[\pL]*
```

In Javascript you can use (set "u" for unicode after delimiter):

```
/[\p{L}]*/u
```